# Get form parameter in EJS template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Hello I'm learning to use Nodejs on my own, and I'm struggling on something that looks really really simple but with fatigue I can't seem to make it work even with an embarassing number of google searches. I tried to unstuck myself but I need help.

Here is part of my code.
I use EJS for the template.

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const querystring = require('querystring');
const url = require('url');


var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const fetch = require("node-fetch");


// URL par défaut
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
 });
//------------------------------------------------------
// Client
 app.get('/client', function (req, res) {
    res.render('client');
 });
 // Edit Client
 app.get('/Eclient, function (req, res) {
    res.render('eclient', {query : req.query});
 });

// set port
 app.listen(3001, function () {
     console.log('Node app is running on port 3001');
 });
 module.exports = app;
```

On my Client page there is a form that is sending to Eclient a parameter called pIDC, with an URL like this :
`http://localhost:3001/Eclient?pIDC=1`
I want to get the value of pIDC on my EJS page with something like `<%= req.query.pIDC%>;` so I can in a second time query the data of the client from my API. But I can't seem to make it work, everytime the data is undefined.

I'm sure it's trivial, but I can't seem to make it work even with all the searches I did. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, you pass to the template through the  variable "query"
like  {query:  req.query} and in template  EJS you get the variable "query" and show it. I include "if" for don't show the variable "query" if we don't have query variable from url.
You can learn more in documentation on EJS

```
<% if (query && query.pIDC) { %>
<%= query.pIDC %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Hello boompro !

The way to do it you showed is how I understood it yes, but it's not working on my end. Maybe I'm missing something.


When there is nothing but HTML and JS on my EJS page, it works fine. But when I add  the code you wrote, or just ```<%= query.pIDC =%>```, it doesn't work anymore. Usually it tells me the variable is undefined, right now it's telling me ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' in C:\Users\Romain\ProjetSynthese\AppliWEB\views\eclient.ejs while compiling ejs
```

My index.js is still the same as above.

Comment: I made a mistake with the same sign equal to the right, fixed above in the code, this works for me

Comment: It works ... I could swear I tried this syntax multiple times. No idea what I did wrong those times but now it works. Thanks !